# Jenkins notification email

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a jenkins pipeline job and pipeline in groovy script. It sends out email
notification every time a job starts and finishes. Now i was told to include the reason for build(ex: git comments, who initiated the job etc) as part of email notification. I am not able to decide how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the API url

```
http://"JENKINS_URL"/job/"JOB_NAME"/"JOB_NUMBER"/api/xml
```

or

```
http://"JENKINS_URL"/job/"JOB_NAME"/"JOB_NUMBER"/api/json
```

for JSON output.

then all you have to do is get the "shortDescription" from there which is the build trigger e.g. `Triggered by GitLab Merge Request #21: "branch name" => master`

Comment: Thanks Raz,
I am getting the json or xml output but i am not able to insert that into the email body which gets triggered when a job is initiated.
Here's is the email format that i am using in the pipeline.

def notify(status){
 emailext(
  to: "xxx@example.com",
  subject: "${status}: Job ${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]",
  body: """${status}: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]',
        Please click ${BUILD_URL}console for more information"""
   )
    }